# Static Launch Screen Images for 11" iPad Pro and 12.9" iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, assets, xcode10.1

How can I update the Assets.xcassets in xcode 10.1 for the new 11" 12.9" iPad Prod any ideas?

[image]